# how to store list into sqlitedatabse?

Tags: android, emulation, contacts, store, sqlite

I need to store list of contacts into sqlite database. I've displayed contacts in my project application using Contacts Content Provider. I  just need to store the list from emulator into database. Anyone knows how? please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big deal.

Transfer your `ContactModel` into a `ContentValue`:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("name", name);
values.put("number", number);
```

then insert it in database :

```
database.insertOrThrow(databaseTable.getTableName(), null, values)
```

But keep in mind that it will always be as fast to get a contact from SQLite database as from the `ContentProvider` since it's pretty the same tech.